Geometrization of a map on a plane
It is probably a question with a simple solution for topologists. However my knowledge of topology is very basic and I don't know the answer.
Suppose we have an arbitrary map on a plane (a set of countries with borders with neighbors).

Can such a map be transformed topologically (I mean continuously
deformed) so that every single boundary between neighbors is a
single straight line or at most two connected straight lines?

And if not, what is the simplest counterexample?

How many straight segments ( minimal number) for a single boundary we need to obtain boundaries in general case?

Assuming  there are counterexamples - how can we discern maps which
can be    transformed this way from maps which are not transformable?


(Let exclude from considerations a trivial case when one region is surrounded entirely by the other - it is obvious that border between them would be at least triangle)

@MoisheKohan San-Marino would have after geometrization three segment border ( triangle) with Itally as totally surrounded (this is what I named a trivial case). Islands I'm excluding from considerations taking into account a rule: one country=one region. So for a proper map every island should be independent country..

Could you make precise what you mean by "arbitrary map on a plane", say, something on the level of "decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into compact sets whose boundary is a Jordan curve and which only intersect each other at their boundaries"?

@BenSteffan Map which can be drawn with continuous lines, these lines can be smooth as possible and after geometrization can be transformed into connected series of line segments with the aim to make for every border the number of lines  as small as possible. I don't know whether it is equivalent to definition of Jordan curve.
